# With Entity Framework how to create nested objects without one massive query resultset or hundreds of small queries?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using EF to populate objects which I then interact with in my business layer code. The objects have several levels but let's first simplify it to a typical master-detail example with `Order` and `OrderLine`.

Let's say I need to retrieve 50 orders each of which has about 100 order lines, and I need all that data. What's the most efficient way of doing this in EF?

If I do it like this:

```
var orders = context.Orders.Where(o => o.Status == "Whatever")
                .Include(order => order.OrderLines)
                .ToList();
```

Then it'll run a single query that pulls back 50x100 rows, then it cleverly assembles that into 50 `Order` objects, each with their own `OrderLine` objects.

If instead I don't do the `Include()` and I later iterate over each `Order` and its `OrderLines`, then it'll issue 50 separate queries to get the `OrderLine` data, i.e. one for each `Order`.

So far the `.Include()` seems great: I pull back a bit more data than needed from SQL but that's much better than issuing 50 extra queries. But is there a way I can choose to issue 2 queries, one to get `Order` and one to get `OrderLine`, and have EF connect the objects automatically?

A more realistic scenario where I want this is if the data is more complex. Let's say I want objects like this (where `Product` is the thing being bought in the `OrderLine` and `ProductPart` is a number of bits used to make the `Product`):

```
- Order
   - OrderLine (avg 100 per Order) 
       - Product (1 per OrderLine)
           - ProductPart (avg 20 per Product)
```

Now if I do a `.Include()` with `ProductPart`, it'll make the query results much bigger. Or if I don't `Include()` then it'll issue separate queries for each `Product`.

Is there a third way where I can get all the `Order`, `OrderLine` and `Product` data in one query and all the `ProductPart` data in another query, and magically have EF connect the objects up for me?

**UPDATE:**

I just read about [`AsSplitQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) which seems to be what I'm looking for but is only available in EF Core 5 which isn't stable till Nov 2020 (?). I'm looking for a way to achieve this in EF6.

A bit more research and I found https://entityframework.net/improve-ef-include-performance which suggests two approaches when you have multiple object types coming off the parent object:

1. Execute multiple EF commands to pull back the same list of parent objects, but each time `Include()`-ing different child object types. EF will hook up the related objects it's already pulled from the db, apparently.
2. Use the EF+ library which seems it can do something like `AsSplitQuery()`

I'm not sure if this works with my case where there's more levels of nesting rather than just different types of objects off the parent. My guess is yes, if I'm clever about it. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are issuing tracking queries, then EF will fixup all the references while the results are being returned. You can also use the `Load` method to load the results & fixup references without constructing a list.

For example;

```cs
var orders = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Status == "Whatever")
    .ToList();

context.OrderLines
    .Where(l => l.Order.Status == "Whatever")
    .Include(l => l.Product) // maybe this is a reasonable tradeoff?
    .Load();

context.ProductPart
    .Where(p => p.Product.OrderLines.Any(l => l.Order.Status == "Whatever"))
    .Load();
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might destructure your object results a bit, but should perform two separate queries.

```
var ordersQuery = context.Orders.Where(o => o.Status == "Whatever");

var orderLineGroups = ordersQuery
   .SelectMany(o => o.OrderLines)
   .ToLookup(l => l.OrderID); // <- Not sure what your FK name is

var orders = ordersQuery.Select(o => new {
   Order = o,
   OrderLines = orderLineGroups[o.Id]
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you need second one with anonymous object? You can just select orders and after that fill in orderlines in foreach.

Comment: Yes, you could, and you would have to include the .Where expression in the second statement as well. But it would work. Just more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that it will work in EF6 but you can try rely on tracking and relationship fix up. Next one works for me in the latest EF Core:

```
public class Make
{
    public int MakeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Model> Models { get; set; }

    public Make()
    {
        Models = new HashSet<Model>();
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Make Make { get; set; }
    public int MakeId { get; set; }
}


ctx.Makes.Where(m => m.Name=="3").SelectMany(m=> m.Models).ToList();
ctx.Makes.Where(m => m.Name=="3").ToList(); // makes have models filled in
```